# Command to Create fresh Aws Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can we create new aws instance ubuntu using cli ? We are facing the problem as we dont have Ami ID for this ?

1.I have all the details like key pair, security group etc

Can anyone help me to get the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ami id base on the Ubuntu version, architecture, instance type and AWS region in the [Ubuntu EC2 AMI locator](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/).

In any case you will need the ami-id.  You can search for an image in the create instance wisard (copy the ami-id when you have found the image you want) or use the [describe-images](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html) command from the cli.